# python 3.4 vs. 3.5 strftime same locale different output

Tags: python, datetime

The execution of these commands in python 3.4.x (Windows 10 Home)

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Spanish')
datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%a %d %b %Y')
```

renders the output

```
'Spanish_Spain.1252'
'mar 07 jun 2016'
```

but with Python 3.5.x the output is

```
'Spanish_Spain.1252'
'ma. 07 jun. 2016'
```

I cannot find anything regarding this change.

Comment: I think it might be something with Windows. At least, I can't reproduce this on my mac (OS X 10.11.5).

Comment: Just a WAG, but this feels like a default / environment issue on what the 'locale' value is. Try setting the locale explicitly (which is *always* the best policy).

Comment: Yes, it has to do with Windows but the output changes from 3.4 to 3.5 in the same system, I wonder if this is some kind of bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I issued the problem to the Python bug tracker and Eryk Sun answered my question:

> The universal CRT that's used by 3.5+ implements locales using Windows
>   locale names [1], which were introduced in Vista. Examples for Spanish
>   include 'es', 'es-ES', and 'es-ES_tradnl' . The latter is the
>   traditional sort for Spain, which has the 3-letter abbreviations for
>   the days of the week. The default for Spain is the modern sort, which
>   uses 2-letter abbreviations.
>
> The old LCID system [2] defaults to the traditional sort (0x40A), to
>   which the old CRT maps unqualified "spanish". The modern sort (0xC0A)
>   is available as "spanish-modern" [3]. The universal CRT still honors
>   "spanish-modern" [4], but just "spanish" by itself is mapped instead
>   to neutral "es", which uses the modern sort.
>
> If you need to use the traditional form in both versions, then in 3.4
>   it's just "spanish", but 3.5+ requires a locale name with the sort
>   suffix. I actually couldn't find a table on MSDN that listed the
>   "tradnl" sort name to append to "es-ES", so I wrote a quick script to
>   find it, assuming at least "tra" would be in the name:
>
> ```
> import re
> import ctypes
>
> kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
>
> LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
>     ctypes.c_int,
>     ctypes.c_wchar_p,
>     ctypes.c_uint,
>     ctypes.c_void_p)
>
> def find_locale(pattern):
>     result = []
>     @LOCALE_ENUMPROCEX
>     def cb(locale, flags, param):
>         if re.match(pattern, locale, re.I):
>             result.append(locale)
>         return True
>     kernel32.EnumSystemLocalesEx(cb, 0, None, None)
>     result.sort()
>     return result
>
> >>> find_locale('es-.*TRA.*')
> ['es-ES_tradnl']
>
> >>> import locale, time
> >>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es-ES_tradnl')
> 'es-ES_tradnl'
> >>> time.strftime('%a')
> 'mié'
> ```
>
> Note that abbreviations in Spanish generally end with a period. It's
>   present for every country except Spain, such as Mexico:
>
> ```
> >>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'spanish_mexico')
> 'Spanish_Mexico.1252'
> >>> time.strftime('%a')
> 'mié.'
> ```
>
> or using the locale name (3.5+):
>
> ```
> >>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es-MX')
> 'es-MX'
> >>> time.strftime('%a')
> 'mié.'
> ```
>
> Note that Python still doesn't support parsing locale names:
>
> ```
> >>> locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\locale.py", line 578, in getlocale
>     return _parse_localename(localename)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\locale.py", line 487, in _parse_localename
>     raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
> ValueError: unknown locale: es-MX
> ```
>
> Since locale names don't include the encoding, parsing them for
>   getlocale() will require an additional call to get the locale's ANSI
>   codepage, in case anyone wants to update the locale module to support
>   this:
>
> ```
> >>> LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE = 0x1004
> >>> buf = (ctypes.c_wchar * 10)()
> >>> kernel32.GetLocaleInfoEx('es-MX', LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, buf, 10)
> 5
> >>> buf.value
> '1252'
> ```
>
> If no one has additional concerns here, I'll close this issue as 3rd
>   party in a day or so. Inconsistencies in the locale that "spanish"
>   maps to in different versions of the CRT are completely Microsoft's
>   problem.
>
> [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373814 [2]:
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693 [3]:
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
>   [4]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf.aspx

http://bugs.python.org/msg267835